# Is it possible to configure multiple/different CallBack queue for RabbitMQ RPC C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, callback, rabbitmq, rpc

I want something Like this...

1. Client Made request.
2. Throught Exchange It's goes to rpc_queue
3. Server Read Request from rpc_queue
4. Server Give reply to different CallBack queue. Different means For X type of response it should go to "Callback queue1" and for Y type of response it should go to "callback queue2"

I am able to till step 3. But have no idea how to configure multiple callback queue. Is it even possible? and if yes, How? please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPC functionality of RabbitMQ works off the "reply-to" settings for a message, which has to be pre-set by the message producer. If you try to use the RPC capabilities, it won't work. You won't be able to get a different message from a different queue, based on what the server says is correct.

To make this work, you will need to build 2-way messaging in to your app, instead of using the RPC semantics and APIs. Meaning, you need to have your message producer - the one that makes the original request - also set up as a message consumer.

The client will make a request via the `rpc_queue` and then it will also listen to both `callback queue 1` and `callback queue 2` as a message consumer.

There are some challenges to this, however. When you receive the message from the callback queues, you don't necessarily have all of the context of the original request anymore - it's not RPC, so it's not just a callback function.

From my [managing long running workflow processes](http://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/) post (which covers JavaScript, but the same principle applies):

> When you have a long running process facilitated by messaging, you may not want to keep the process object around in memory all the time. If there are hundreds or thousands of these instances running, that could eat up a lot of memory. Additionally, you have no guarantee that the server won’t go down and come back up in between messages that are sent back and forth.
>
> In my email course / ebook on RabbitMQ Patterns, I talk about the challenge of ensuring the response message is handled by the right object.
>
> The easiest way to do this is to again use the Correlation ID of the message. By sending an ID with the original command, and returning it with each status event message, you can apply the message to the correct job. The correlation ID in a typical request / response scenario will likely be a random GUID or UUID. In the case of the job status events, however, the correlation ID should be the job’s unique ID. This makes it trivial to find the job to which the event message applies, and update the job accordingly.
>
> If the original object that is managing the workflow is no longer in memory, you will have to reconstruct that object when a related message comes in. This is where the correlation ID that is mentioned above comes in to play. The correlation ID should be examined when a message arrives, and the correct workflow object should be loaded in to memory again. Once that has been done, the message can be processed by object, the state can be saved and then the workflow object can be unloaded from memory once more.
>
> To make this happen, the code will have to be adjusted significantly with the message listener and workflow object relationship inverted.

I've also written about this more, in my [RabbitMQ Patterns](http://derickbailey.com/email-courses/rabbitmq-patterns-for-applications/) email course / ebook (which is not specific to a programming language).